# What is the +AF8 in Amazon Glacier's archive paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I get the contents of a Glacier vault via the Java SDK, the path of the archive contains **+AF8** every so often. What is the purpose/meaning of it?

actual: JG+AF8-Foo/bar+AF8-2014-05-29+AF8-00-08.txt.zip

instead of: JG-Foo/bar-2014-05-29-00-08.txt.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a decoding error. If you [read here](http://www.string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=65000&decoding=10000) you will see that +AF8- appears to be the Mac encoding for an underscore `_`

I think you may need to apply a decode function, or use a different one in Java to resolve this.